# Badly uploaded images to browser

Tags: image, web, memory, browser, cpu

we have problems with badly uploaded images to our web application. It cannot be reproduced on local, but the problem is reported by clients. Images are cutted in some part and filled with random color(mostly grey) I attched exapmle images. Problem is on web part because our checksums are correct on server. This is not language problem it's occur on javascript and flex app. Files are also correct. In first attempt image was badly uploaded but when you try to upload it again it will be ok. We are not sure but maybe it's problem with memory or cpu is too burdened client's reported us the browser was acting weird. Is anyone had this problem or know source of it. Any hints will be welcome

[Example image A](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jNW5s.png)
[Example image B](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9BSKI.png)

Comment: Hello? Couldn't I helped you?

Comment: Hi, no, but thanks for spending your time, we have problems on browser-application upload, checksums are correct on app and server. We tried to find this photos using pixels checks on canvas and it's took an exam for part of badly uploaded photos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those are corrupted images. JPEG data interruptions lead to grey areas in the image (usually at the bottom or right). It happens, if the upload stream was interrupted or completely lost.

[image]
[image]
<sup>example images by https://www.jpeg-repair.org/</sup>

A server will automatically detect a damaged stream (see [TCP and UDP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_layer)), so I think it is caused by a timeout or another error resulting in an end of the stream.

I would guess that the back-end makes the mistake not to care about why the upload ends and continues processing, instead of canceling, even if the file was only partly uploaded. And because I don't know anything about your server infrastructure, I can't tell you how to fix this.

**Btw.:** You can reproduce this locally using [Chromes built-in simulator of a slower network connection](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/network#throttle). Just upload the image very very slow (e.g. with option "Slow 3G" activated) and then cut of the connection while uploading (with option "Offline"). But you may need many tries to reproduce it.